# White flash after Splash Screen on Android React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, splash-screen

I have a React Native App built with ExpoKit SDK 32. I have a main switch navigator (from React Navigation) which starts with a Loading Screen, there I do some business logic to decide what screen should load next (Screen A or B), on the next screen I disable the Splash Screen.
The problem is: Whenever I move from the Loading Screen to screen A, I get a White flash.
I have not seem it happen on iOS, only on Android.
Screen A has a imageBackground Component on the whole screen. The image is cached and its the same as the splash screen.

I've tried rendering an image equal to the SplashScreen on the background of the Loading Screen. Same result.

Then I put on my componentDidMount of Screen A `SplashScren.hide()`. Same result.

The best outcome as been putting 'SplashScreen.hide()' on the onLoadEnd of my background Image of Screen A.

Any help is appreciated! Is there a better way to deal with this kind of situation involving the Switch Component on React Navigation?

This is how my Screen A looks now:

```
async imageLoaded() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
    try {
      const usuario = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(LOGIN_USUARIO_LOCAL_AUTH);
      if (usuario) {
        await this.localAuth();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // faz nada
    }
  }

....

 render() {
    const { usuario, senha } = this.state;
    const { logando, localAuthHardware } = this.props;

    const labelHardware = localAuthLabel(localAuthHardware);

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('../../../assets/images/start.png')}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.container}
          imageStyle={styles.container}
          onLoadEnd={this.imageLoaded}
          fadeDuration={0}
        >
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView alwaysBounceVertical={false} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
            <Image
              source={require('../../../assets/images/baladapp-icone.png')}
              style={styles.baladappicone}
              resizeMode="contain"
              fadeDuration={0}
            />
            <View style={styles.baladappView}>
              <Image
                source={require('../../../assets/images/BaladAPP.png')}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={styles.baladapp}
                fadeDuration={0}
              />
              <Text style={styles.produtorText}>PRODUTOR</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.formView}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Usuário"
                style={[styles.input, { elevation: 1.3 }]}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                value={usuario}
                onChangeText={this.changeUsuario}
                keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'email-address' : 'visible-password'}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize="none"
              />
              <PasswordInputField
                placeholder="Senha"
                style={styles.input}
                enablesReturnKeyAutomatically
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                value={senha}
                onChangeText={this.changeSenha}
                containerStyle={[styles.containerPasswordStyle, { elevation: 1.3 }]}
                onSubmitEditing={this.login}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.abrirRecuperarSenha}
                style={styles.esqueceuTextView}
                hitSlop={hitSlop15}
              >
                <Text style={styles.esqueceuText}>Esqueceu a senha?</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Button
                text="ACESSAR SISTEMA"
                containerStyle={styles.button}
                textStyle={styles.buttonText}
                onPress={this.login}
                loading={logando}
                loadingColor={colors.branco}
              />
              {localAuthHardware.length > 0 && (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={this.localAuth}
                  style={styles.localAuthView}
                  hitSlop={hitSlop15}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.esqueceuText}>{`Acessar com ${labelHardware}`}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            </View>
          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </ImageBackground>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```